# Keyboard not showing for UITextView after hiding it using [self endEditing:YES]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITextView that is created programmatically on viewDidLoad using the method below. Keyboard is shown successfully right after  `[_answerTextView becomeFirstResponder]` is called. And hid if the user enters return(\n) character.

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [self endEditing:YES];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

After the keyboard is hid by the code above, I'm not able to bring it back anymore by tapping the UITextView again.

I tried showing the keyboard by calling `[_answerTextView becomeFirstResponder]` on Tap event for the parent UIView and it worked. But that's not what I want.

UITextView is created by the method below;

```
-(UITextView*)createSurveyTextView{
    _answerTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _optionsStackView.frame.size.width, 200)];
    _answerTextView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    _answerTextView.text = @"";
    _answerTextView.editable = true;
    _answerTextView.selectable = true;
    _answerTextView.delegate = self;
    [_answerTextView becomeFirstResponder];

    _answerTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _answerTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _answerTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [_optionsStackView addSubview:_answerTextView];

    _answerTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    [_answerTextView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [_optionsStackView bringSubviewToFront:_answerTextView];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:_answerTextView];
    [_answerTextView setUserInteractionEnabled:true];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *mainViewTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTextViewTap:)];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap2:)];

    [_answerTextView addGestureRecognizer:mainViewTap];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tap2];

    return _answerTextView;
}
```

I want the UITextView to simply show the keyboard when the user taps on it self. What am I missing?

Edit: I have the same sources in another view, but everything works fine there. The only difference is, here the UITextView is created programmatically.

Edit 2: I got it worked. The `_optionsStackView` that the UITextView is added as a child is a UIStackView. I tried adding the `_answerTextView` to the parent UIView and everything works fine now. What would be the problem with the UIStackView?

Comment: I have a feeling you can't call `[self endEditing:YES];` before you return `shouldChangeTextInRange:`. Try delaying that using dispatch_async and see if that works. If that _does_ work, try replacing `endEditing:` with `resignFirstResponder:` on your Textfield. See if that has any different behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem very strange in your code.You can explantion why use UITapGestureRecognizer to this UITextView control.How do you think this lead to conflict?

I find your problem where in start,but I create new project to ensure.So I confirm that UITextView already has target with itself.Also you can't to add UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Hi @Jaeda, I use UITapGestureRecognizer for debug purpose to find out if there is any transparent overlay or if the UI is somehow locked for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You did not use common way to hide/close the keyboard.

Try this common way:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    return [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This is a method in the UITextFieldDelegate, use it and remove your code:

```
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [self endEditing:YES];
        return NO;
}
```

Edit:
@siburb You are right. My bad. 
UITapGestureRecognizer maybe the root cause.

Edit:
@Semih Akbas

Repalce:
[_optionsStackView addSubview:_answerTextView];

To:
[_optionsStackView addArrangedSubview:_answerTextView];

Comment: The OP is using a `UITextView` not a `UITextField`. There's no `textViewShouldReturn:` method in the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol, and it is perfectly fine to use `shouldChangeTextInRange:` to intercept the enter key and `resignFirstResponder`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is almost correct, but just try changing `endEditing:` to `[textView resignFirstResponder]`:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

If that doesn't work, then it *could* be that one of your gestures is preventing the `UITextView`'s own `UITapGestureRecognizer` from receiving the tap. Try disabling (or comment out the creation of) both of your recognizers to verify that it is the issue. If it is, then you can fix it using the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods.

Comment: Will try this and let you know @siburp.

Comment: Unfortunately did not work :(. I've removed all tap definitions and methods and changed endEditing to resignFirstResponder, but no chance... I have the same sources in another view, but everything works fine there. The only difference is, here the UITextView is created programmatically.